# newcommand and index

Tags: macros, indexing

I want to have an index entry referencing to another entry withought adding a comma.
I currently do this with:

```
\newcommand{\gobblecomma}[1]{}
```

And then in the text itself when an entry occurs:

```
\index{<Entry>!{}\gobblecomma@|seealso{<AlsoEntry>}}
```

This above part produces exactly the index format I am looking for.
However, since this is a rather long bit for the second line to type each time in my text where I have such an entry I want to shorten this.
I tried to use:

```
\newcommand{\gobblecomma}[1]{}
\newcommand{\alsoindex}[2]{\index{#1!{}\gobblecomma@|seealso{#2}}}
```

and then in the text itself:

```
\alsoindex{<Entry>}{<AlsoEntry>}
```

However, this completely ignores the "\gobblecomma@" part.
How can I solve this?
Compilable it looks like this:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside, a4paper, twocolumn, openany, makeidx]{book}

\usepackage[totoc, initsep=0pt, columns=4]{idxlayout}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\newcommand{\gobblecomma}[1]{}
\newcommand{\alsoindex}[2]{\index{#1!{}\gobblecomma@|seealso{#2}}}
\makeatother
\makeindex

\begin{document}

random text entry

\index{Entry}
\alsoindex{Entry}{Alsoentry}

random other entry text

\index{Otherentry}
\index{Otherentry!{}\gobblecomma@|seealso{Alsoentry}}

more random text

\clearpage
\printindex

\end{document}
```

The difference is just in the presence of the comma before the "see also" in the end result.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Can you please make your code snippets compilable ...

Comment: `\string\gobblecomma@`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Your suggestion makes Janssen's command work exactly the way I want, at least! Many thanks! Good idea, Jannsen, for making a command to do that - I was having a hard time remembering that unusual syntax every time.